# Execute specific command from plasmoid

Tags: qt4, kde-plasma, plasmoid

I'm writing a Remote Control Plasmoid, I want it to send certain commands over ssh to a remote host, I've tried:

```
QProcess p;
p.start("/home/user/bin/command");
p.waitfForFinished(-1);
```

where `command` is a script which has

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@remote_host remote_command &> /dev/null &
```

I've also tried using

```
KRun::run(QString("/home/user/bin/command"), NULL);
```

but it does nothing, perhaps I'm using it the wrong way?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

OK, my problem was that I didn't connect the signals correctly, now I've done that and this part of code works perfectly.

best regards!